# How to do check the paragraphs content to read a .docx file line-by-line in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

After upload I want to read a **.docx file** line by line.

My **file.docx** is divided for **chapters** and **paragraphs** of the **chapter**

The structure of **file.docx**

```
Chapter 1 - Events
alert or disservices
significant activities

Chapter 2 – Safety
near miss
security checks

Chapter 3 – Training
environment
upkeep
```

I have tried using [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word/) to read the document.

The whole document

[image]

Now according to the chapter I have to insert chapter and content of the paragraph in the corresponding database table

e.g.

```
Chapter 1 - Events
 - alert or disservices
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ….
…. ….
…. ….
- significant activities
Phasellus dui nunc, rutrum vitae dictum eleifend, ullamcorper hendrerit sem ….
…. ….
…. ….
```

Must be inserted in the table `Events`

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for events
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `events`;
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alert_or_disservices` longtext,
  `significant_activities` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please can you help me?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion

My code below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Application word = new Application();
        object miss = Missing.Value;
        object path = @"C:\\file.docx";
        object readOnly = true;
        Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss,
                                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, 
                                            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        string totaltext = "";      //the whole document

        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
        {   
            totaltext += docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString() + "<br />";
        }

        Response.Write(totaltext);
        docs.Close();
        word.Quit();
    }
}
```

**Update #1**

1. the chapters identifiable by heading
2. alert or disservices is just preceded by a text hyphen
3. each new paragraph begin with by a text hyphen
4. no hard returns/paragraph marks present within the alert blocks
5. for each chapter I have created a table with the headings of the columns equal to those of the paragraphs, but if there is a better solution, it's welcome

I would like to share my file .docx for your download but I don't know how.

I tried with `wetransfer` but it was not approved because it's an untrusted source

**update #2**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var wdApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        var doc = wdApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\\file.docx");

        var ran = doc.Content;
        var fin = ran.Find;
        fin.ClearFormatting();
        fin.MatchWildcards = false;
        fin.Text = "";
        fin.set_Style("Chapter 1 - Events"); //use your heading style here, e.g. Heading 1
        fin.Execute();
        while (fin.Found)
        {
            var chap = ran.Text;

            //cut off "Chapter[space]" from start, clean text from trailing carriage returns and stuff
            chap = chap.Substring(8).TrimEnd('\r', '\n', '\t', ' ');

            //Heading ended by hard return/para mark; get text of following paragraph '-alert or disservice'
            ran = doc.Range(ran.End, ran.End).Paragraphs[1].Range;
            var subhead = ran.Text;

            //clean subheading of leading hyphen and space, trailing stuff
            subhead = subhead.TrimStart(' ', '-').TrimEnd('\r', '\n', '\t', ' ');

            //get text under subheading = contents, clean up
            ran = doc.Range(ran.End, ran.End).Paragraphs[1].Range;
            var contents = ran.Text;
            contents = contents.TrimEnd('\r', '\n', '\t', ' ');

            //write to db
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;

            string strSql = @"INSERT INTO Chapters (chapter, subheading, contents) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSql))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", chap);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", subhead);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", contents);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            ran = doc.Range(ran.End, doc.Content.End);
            fin = ran.Find;
            fin.ClearFormatting();
            fin.MatchWildcards = false;
            fin.Text = "";
            fin.set_Style("Chapter 1 - Events"); //use your heading style here, e.g. Heading 1
            fin.Execute();
        }
        doc.Close(false);
        wdApp.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Could you give an outline in your own words what this is all about?

Comment: BTW: _Noone_ is going to download a docx from an untrusted source.

Comment: I need insert into database table the lines contained within the file docx. If the lines of file docx starting with `Chapter 1 - Events` the paragraphs of `Chapter 1 - Events` must be inserted in the table corresponding to `Chapter 1 - Events`

Comment: @Fildor is `WeTransfer`... suggest a trusted source please

Comment: _You_ are the untrusted source ;D (No offense). This is like clicking the link in an email that says "Hey, could you download this word please?" - Would you do it? My IT Dept. would hang me on the flag post outside.

Comment: @Fildor Okay should i delete the file download?

Comment: OK, but anyway. I don't see any code where you check the paragraphs' content. You just seem to convert to some mixture of plain text with html newline and return that?

Comment: _"should i delete the file download?"_ I personally would. I don't think it contributes to the question.

Comment: @Fildor This is my problem. How to do check the paragraphs' content?

Comment: Aha ... so the _actual_ question is: How to _find_ the appropriate paragraphs ... right?

Comment: @Fildor Right !!!

Comment: I upvoted to gain attention. Myself, I am not familiar with Office integration. You _may_ want to consider editing that question, so you give a course overview over what you are trying to do first, then go into detail. Maybe focus a bit on the part where you try to identify the paragraphs you are looking for.

Comment: I am relatively familiar with both Interop and Word VBA. I would assume that clever use of the Range.Find method would be better suited for this task. Please explain the structure of the document a bit more: Are the chapters identifiable by style, e.g. heading1? Are you using Number Styles? Is `alert or disservices` a proper bullet list item or just preceded by a text hyphen? Are there any hard returns/paragraph marks present within the `alert`blocks?

Comment: Also: you create your table with a `alert_or_disservices` column, yet only chapter 1 has this subitem, and the other chapters have different ones`? Does not sound like a logical table design.

Comment: @LocEngineer thanks for your interest, please see **update #1** in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Plan B.

The database: a table for each chapter is bad design. I therefore used one table for all of it.

This one is a bit quick and dirty. Normally you would have one table for the chapters, one for the subchapters with a column for chapter ID. I recommend improving this once it works.

This is SQLite but you can easily adapt this to InnoDb:

```
CREATE TABLE Chapters (
    sID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    chapter text NOT NULL,
    subheading1 text NOT NULL,
    contents1 text NULL,
    subheading2 text NOT NULL,
    contents2 text NULL
)
```

Since we are basically handling plain text, let us reduce Interop to a bare minimum and do the rest with regex:

```
var wdApp = new Word.Application();
var doc = wdApp.Documents.Open(@"D:\00_Projekte_temp\Lorem ipsum.docx");

var txt = doc.Content.Text;


doc.Close(false);
wdApp.Quit();

var rex = new Regex(@"(Chapter[\s\t])(.+?)([\r\n]+?)(\s?\-\s?)(.+?[\r\n]+?)(.+?)([\r\n]+?)(\-\s)(.+?[\r\n]+?)(.+?[\r\n])");
var mCol = rex.Matches(txt);

foreach (Match m in mCol)
{
    var chap = m.Groups[2].Value;
    var subh1 = m.Groups[5].Value;
    var cont1 = m.Groups[6].Value;
    var subh2 = m.Groups[9].Value;
    var cont2 = m.Groups[10].Value;

   //write to db
    var strSql = @"INSERT INTO Chapters (chapter, subheading1, contents1, subheading2, contents2) VALUES ($chap, $sub1, $con1, $sub2, $con2)";
    using (var con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source =\"D:\\00_Projekte_temp\\wordtest.db\";Version=3"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(strSql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$chap", chap);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$sub1", subh1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$con1", cont1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$sub2", subh2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$con2", cont2);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I also recommend for the future that either your authors send you plain text directly or that you move from Interop to OpenXml, since that makes you independent from Word and thus also runnable on a server.

Comment: thanks you so much for help. I have tried your suggestion without success, I have error on this line `fin.set_Style("Chapter 1 - Events");` the error is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException, HResult=0x800A16CA, Message=The item with the specified name does not exist.` Please see **update #2** in the question

Comment: @ChevyMarkSunderland As the code says: here you tell the find method what *style* to look for. Not what *text* that style is written in. It must be `fin.set_Style("Heading 1")` or whatever style your text "Chapter x - ..." is written in.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand if set `fin.set_Style("Heading 1")` the visual studio debug is infinite loop

Comment: Use single step (F10) to step through your code. Also, make sure your document is not being blocked in background by an orphaned Word process. Use Task Manager to check for Word processes, make sure Word and your document are closed when executing this code.

Comment: Okay. The document is unlocked and I have killed all Word processes in Task Manager. The error not change `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException, HResult=0x800A16CA, Message=The item with the specified name does not exist.` Please explain better what it means `Heading 1` and what I have to insert on `fin.set_Style("Heading 1")`

Comment: See my edit in the answer above.

Comment: thank you. Now the error is `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string` in this line in your code `chap = chap.Substring(8).TrimEnd('\r', '\n', '\t', ' ');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221692/discussion-between-locengineer-and-chevy-mark-sunderland).

Comment: sorry i have new problems, recorded only the first line of the paragraph
- significant activities
Phasellus dui nunc, rutrum vitae dictum eleifend, ullamcorper hendrerit sem
- security checks
Phasellus mollis dapibus porta. Phasellus ac tristique dui
- upkeep
Mauris id elit nec nisl laoreet posuere. Donec ac molestie sem
not registered are misses

Comment: Yes. Just like I said in my last comment in chat. Solving this with interop on a document without styles is not efficient. Please either apply styles or ditch interop and use txt + regex.

Comment: This file docx is worked on and uploaded by different people by different days... I can't ask everyone to change or applies styles... really I don't understand this new problem......

Comment: In that case you might have a whole different problem, namely with your general process. You might want to start thinking about using a content management system or authoring system. You seem to have your process backwards. With your obviously distributed author system, your authors should be using a common system backed by a database rather than Word with you trying to pry the contents from single files. Who knows, maybe Confluence or Wordpress could do the trick for you, maybe even a Wiki.

Comment: too difficult to change modes or rethink method ... all users using this format docx long since...  it would be enough to understand why the script record only the first line of the paragraph

Comment: Switched to plan B, see above. Please also not the change in table design as well as the recommendation for future clean table design.